# Python: Import date-time from .txt file into separate lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, datetime, import

I'm trying to read in multiple columns of date and time data from a .txt file into python.

An accurate example of the file (with the same spacing) is:

```
Unrequired info
Unrequired info

Unrequired info
Initial start:     Main start:     Recovery start:     Recovery end:     H:
yyyymmdd hh:mm          yyyymmdd hh:mm          yyyymmdd hh:mm          yyyymmdd hh:mm               nT
20030817 05:06          20030819 05:06          20030901 05:06          20030902 05:06                -10
20040713 21:22          20040716 23:42          20040717 02:41          20040718 16:09                -93
```

There are then multiple rows of date time information.

I want to read in the date time information from separate columns into separate lists or arrays either as strings or in datetime format. I don't need the data from the final column.

This is the code that I have tried so far:

```
InitialStart = []
MainStart = []
RecoveryStart = []
RecoveryEnd = []


with open('list.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()[6:]
    for row in file:
        a, b, c, d, e = row.split()
        InitialStart.append(str(a))
        MainStart.append(str(b))
        RecoveryStart.append(str(c))
        RecoveryEnd.append(str(d))
```

When `print(InitialStart)` is added to the code, the only result printed is `[]`

The expected out put is for lists with date-time data as strings in each element.

Comment: Looks like the dates are tab delimited. Try split('\t') ?

Comment: for row in lines:

Comment: It would change the way you interact with the data(in a dataframe instead of lists), but panda's [read_fwf](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) is meant for parsing this type of file.

Comment: Tried using `split('\t')` instead, only result printed when `print(InitialStart)` is used is `[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague provided the answer ([`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)) to this, so I'm going to answer my own question.

`listTable = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer='list.txt', sep='\s{2,}', names=['InitialStart', 'MainStart', 'RecoveryStart', 'RecoveryEnd', 'H'], dtype='str', engine='python', skiprows=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5))`

`sep='\s{2,}'` sets the separation to whitespace (`\s`) and `{2,}` sets it to 2 or more (more commands can be seen [here](https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/)).